# Driving directions on Google Earth

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

How to "draw" directions on Google Earth, but without usage of google maps like in this example http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/drive-simulator/index.html
In my case longitude and latitude for start and end points is provided by Winform application and Google Earth itself is displayed in winform WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google.maps.DirectionsService() is of google.maps!
So you can not avoid maps if you use DirectionService.
If you dont want to see map pane,please "hide" the map container
anyway by your powerfull "Winform" utility or .slideToggle().